# How to draw RGB image buffer or CVPixelBufferRef on NSOpenGLView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl, nsopenglview

I have `NSOpenGLView` on form and frame buffer event from `AVFoundation`. I want to show video `frames` on my form using `OpenGL` View.

Comment: Well, it's the fastest way. NSImageBiew for example must simpler but take too high CPU usage. Right now I have checked very difficult samples from Apple but they too complex too understood, I just need to draw an image.

Comment: Fastest way?? What computer are you running even a really slow computer these days can show a video frame...

Comment: Nono my point is that most computers are fast enough that you don't need to use OpenGL to display a video frame..

Comment: Yes, but if you want to capture video on-the-fly and perform video and audio processing - better to use OpenGL.

Comment: Except from your question you sound like you know nothing about OpenGL, or video processing in general.

Comment: I know a lot about video processing, DirectShow and DirectX. But newbie in Cocoa/OpenGL. Implemented using OpenGL, worked better, CPU usage is much lower.